# Read a non JSON file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The data in sakey-data.json file is array of arrays.

```
[
       [ 'Brazil', 'Portugal', 5 ],
       [ 'Brazil', 'France', 1 ],
       [ 'Brazil', 'Spain', 1 ],
       [ 'Brazil', 'England', 1 ]
]
```

I have been using this factory service to fetch the data.

```
app.factory('SankeyData', ['$http', function($http){

    return $http.get('http://localhost:4000/data/sakey-data.json')
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            return err;
        });

}]);
```

It is unable to get data. Rather it shows this error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

There is no syntax error at all. If I change the GET URL to actual JSON format file everything works well.

And moreover I can not change the format of this data in file because Google Graph API needs data in this format.

Please help me find a solution to fetch such files from server using AngularJS.

Comment: As per [the specification](http://json.org/). JSON strings have to be quoted in double quotes (`"`) rather than single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Can you show your call to the SankeyData factory ? Actually you can't return data in a success like that.

Comment: You can return data "like that" in success but in this case only if `transformResponse` is overriden.

Comment: @MikkoViitala Sorry i didn't give enought explanation. I meant you can't return data "this way". The return function in .success will fire and ... return data to nothing. the .success handling the data shouldn't be in the factory.

Comment: Yes, true. Factory as it is, is not going to work but I assumed it's copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As state by @Phylogenesis you really should replace `'` with `"`.
If that's not an option, then you can configure `$http` to transform the response.

```
angular.module('app',[])

  .controller('MainCtrl', function(SankeyData) {
    SankeyData.getData().then(function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  })

  .factory('SankeyData', function($q, $http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:4000/data/sakey-data.json';
    return {
      getData: function() {
        return $http({ 
          url: url, 
          transformResponse: function(response) {
            return response.replace(/\'/g, '"');
          },
        }).then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      } 
    };
  });
```

---

[image: imgur]

Comment: will still be a string and JSON.parse won't convert it ...answer doesn't deal with how OP would convert to javascript array from string

Comment: Edited my answer to deal with it.

Comment: Down vote, eh? Probably from my personal, serial downvoter? No? Then please, leave a comment so I can improve my answer.